# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to Select Records based on logged in user role using DB Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Entity Framework Db Identity, I am implementing Role Based Application.

Each User can only have just one Role.

There are there roles:

```
Admin
Teacher
Student
```

If **Role is Student**, the application should query:

```
var examScores = _dbContext.Scores
            .Where(m => (bool)m.Approval.IsFirstLevel == false)
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery)
        || x.Subject.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
return examScores;
```

If **Role is Teacher**, the application should query:

```
var examScores = _dbContext.Scores
            .Where(m => (bool)m.Approval.IsSecondLevel == false)
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery)
        || x.Subject.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
return examScores;
```

If **Role is Admin**, the application should query:

```
var examScores = _dbContext.Scores
            .Where(m => (bool)m.Approval.IsFirstLevel && (bool)m.Approval.IsSecondLevel)
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery)
        || x.Subject.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
return examScores;
```

So far, this is what I have done:

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<ScoreListDto>>>>> GetExamScoreAsync([FromQuery] PagingFilter filter)
{
    var result = await _examScoresService.GetExamScoreAsync(filter);

    return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
}
```

**Service:**

```
   public async Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<ScoreListDto>>>> GetScoreAsync(PagingFilter filter)
    {
        var score = await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreAsync(filter);
        var item = await score.PaginationAsync<Score, ScoreListDto>(filter.PageSize, filter.PageNumber, _mapper);
        return new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<ScoreListDto>>>()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Successful = true,
            Data = item
        };
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Score>> GetExamScoreAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
        var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;
        var getUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        var loggedUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(getUser);
        var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();
}
```

This is the flow of the application

```
Repository -> Service -> Controller
```

How do I implement **var examScores** into my code based on (condition) the role of the logged in user?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know the role of the user in the code?

Comment: @Chetan - var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString(); as shown in the Repository in my code above is what I use to know the role of the user

Answer (score 0):

Since your queries as far as I can see only vary on the first `Where` clause you could do either;

1)

Build the query by chaining commands to an `IQueryable<Score>`.

```cs
var query = loggedUserRoleName switch {
    "Student" => _dbContext.Scores.Where(m => (bool)m.Approval.IsFirstLevel == false),
    "Teacher" => _dbContext.Scores.Where(m => (bool)m.Approval.IsSecondLevel == false),
    "Admin" => _dbContext.Scores.Where(m => (bool)m.Approval.IsFirstLevel && (bool)m.Approval.IsSecondLevel),
    _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown role {loggedUserRoleName}")
};

return query.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery)
        || x.Subject.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
```

2. 

Build the query using a `Dictionary<>` having the role as key and filter expression as value.

```cs
Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Score, bool>>> filters = new() {
    {"Student", m => (bool)m.Approval.IsFirstLevel == false},
    {"Teacher", m => (bool)m.Approval.IsSecondLevel == false}
    {"Admin", m => (bool)m.Approval.IsFirstLevel && (bool)m.Approval.IsSecondLevel}
};
return _dbContext.Scores
            .Where(filters[loggedUserRoleName])
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery)
        || x.Subject.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
```